Pulse width modulation using ML4800CP
I am working on a SMPS (450 V output). It use an ML4800CP IC to control and manage 450 V DC.
How can I measure the PWM signal using an oscilloscope? I attached it, and it worked well for the PFC signal, but I couldn’t sense PWM, maybe due to there being no load. It approaches 450 V immediately and I couldn’t get any PWM waveform.
Can I apply a dummy load so that the PWM continues? If yes, then how much load? Is there some other way to get a wave form on my oscilloscope?

You know what the expected load of your power supply is, so calculate a suitable resistance. Use a couple of incandescent light bulbs if necessary.
